How to disable cookies for all sites while allowing them for some sites as exceptions using selenium python or using selenium chrome options
For my crawling project, I'm trying to block popups for all sites using selenium and python.
The following chrome_options settings helped me block pop ups for some sites but it is also blocking some sites to load:
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins")
)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript": 1,
    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications":2,
    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups":2,
    "profile.block_third_party_cookies": True,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
})

I tried multiple options and also this for these two sites to load but they load blank on using block all cookies.
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2,
"profile.managed_default_content_settings.cookies":1,
"profile.content_settings.exceptions.cookies":{
     "https://www.misterspex.de/":{"setting":1},
     "https://www.kabum.com.br/":{"setting":1}

How can I create an exception for some sites while blocking cookies for the rest using chrome_options or using something within the code?

It's not real clear why you are blocking cookies... do some sites only display popups when certain cookies exist?  Also remember that the driver never switches context (tab/window) unless you tell it to... so popups shouldn't interfere with your scripts.

Blocking cookies helped me remove pop ups and notifications on some sites. Yes, data is accessible even with pop ups. I have the task to remove pop ups. I have solved the issue with if else temporarily as allow for certain urls and block for all

I replaced cookie blocking option with this line:
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1 if allow_cookies else 
                                                  2

and added this to filter urls:
 if url in ["https://www.misterspex.de/", 'https://www.kabum.com.br/']:
        driver = setup_driver(allow_cookies=True)
    else:
        driver = setup_driver(allow_cookies=False)

